# angular material select is not working properly

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using material select in my angular 2 application but the up and down keys are not working properly as they are unable to navigate to other options here is my code

```
 <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">                    
    <mat-select placeholder="Trader Type"  formControlName="TraderType">
        <mat-option value="Seller">Seller</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="Buyer" >Buyer</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="Both">Both</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
 <mat-form-field>
```

and I have imported  MatSelectModule, in my module 
Can anyone tell me what am I missing.

Comment: is the select working ?

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: select is working fine but if i use the up or down key it doesn't change option

Comment: Can you please reproduce issue in the [plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/c3X1LgcC64NkIlEVfUzL?p=preview)?

Comment: are you import hummerjs?